# return data from method c#

Tags: c#, methods, return

I use this method and need return `weights8spr`, but I don't know how. 
Can anybody help me? simplest `return(weights8spr)` don't work, because in input Im not give the double array.

```
public class Run {
    public Run(List<dataVM2> TrainDataForStations)
    {
        double[] resultMAX1 = new double[] { 40.0, 1200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 10000.0 };
        double[] resultMIN1 = new double[] { -50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
        double d1 = 0.0;
        double d2 = 1.0;
        int numItemsspr = TrainDataForStations.Count;
        double[][] trainData = new double[numItemsspr][];
        Random rnd = new Random(1);
        double[][] MassiveDataspr8 = new double[numItemsspr][];
        for (var i = 0; i < numItemsspr; ++i)
        {

            trainData[i] = new double[] { TrainDataForStations[i].TemperatureC1, TrainDataForStations[i].SolarRadiation1, TrainDataForStations[i].Wetness1, TrainDataForStations[i].WindSpeed1, TrainDataForStations[i].gen1 };
        }
        int maxcol = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < trainData.Length; i++)
        {
            if (trainData[i].Length > maxcol)
                maxcol = trainData[i].Length;
        }
        //data normalization 
        for (int j = 0; j < MassiveDataspr8.Length; j++)
        {
            MassiveDataspr8[j] = new double[maxcol];
            for (int i = 0; i < maxcol; i++)
            {
                MassiveDataspr8[j][i] = (((trainData[j][i] - resultMIN1[i]) * (d2 - d1)) / (resultMAX1[i] - resultMIN1[i])) + d1;

            }
        }
        int NumInput = 4;
        int NumHidden = 25;
        int NumOutput = 1;
        int rndSeed = 0;

        NeuralNetworkData neuralform = new NeuralNetworkData(NumInput, NumHidden, NumOutput, rnd);
        int maxEpochs = 1000;
        double learnRate = 0.005;
        double momentum = 0.001;
        double[] weights8spr = new NeuralNetworkTrainer(neuralform, rnd).Train(MassiveDataspr8, maxEpochs, learnRate, momentum);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing that code in the constructor of a class and you can't change the return type of a constructor.

You should create a method in the class and refactor the code a little.

```
public class Run 
{        
    // default constructor not needed
    public Run()
    {
    }

    public double[] RunMethod(List<dataVM2> TrainDataForStations)
    {
        // put your code here
        // ...

        // return the double[]
        return weights8spr;
    }
}
```

And execute like:

```
var run = new Run();
var weights = run.RunMethod(listOfTrainDataForStations);
```

Answer (score 0):

A method must have a return type. If it doesn't return a value, then this would be the pseudo type `void`, otherwise a real one.

```
public class StationsTrainer {
    public double[] Run(List<dataVM2> TrainDataForStations)
    {
        ...
        double[] weights8spr = new NeuralNetworkTrainer(neuralform, rnd)
            .Train(MassiveDataspr8, maxEpochs, learnRate, momentum);
        return weights8spr;
    }
}
```

And choose a better name for the class. E.g. `StationsTrainer`.

Comment: I try this one but have an error in `Run`. The error is  "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"

Comment: Change the name of the class to `StationsTrainer`. You cannot have the class name be the same as the method name, as the exception message tells you. (member = method, property etc.; enclosing type = class or struct.)